# React Native Modal visible prop does nothing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-modal

Hello I am trying to put a simple react native modal in my react native app (running it on expo) but it is always visible. When I set the visible prop to false, it still displays. The relevant code is below:

Main Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Modal} from 'react-native';

class Home extends Component {
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal visible={false}>
          <Text>Test</Text>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
```

Basically the modal is always displaying, even though visible is set to false. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try many ways want to found the problem. The result is:

It seems couldn't work correct on "web site" show, but work on ios or Android emulator.

I try your code on [Doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal) could work, but on sandbox(web site) couldn't.

Maybe you could change to try on other emulator or Expo except "web apps" like "expo ios" or "expo Android"?

Comment: Omg that's very frustrating but thank you! I will try it and if it works I'll let you know and give you credit!

Comment: After getting sidetracked and not being able to work on the project, I finally got it working on the emulator. Your were right, it doesn't work in the web view but it works on the emulators. Thank you for your help 高鵬翔!